# App self unInstall iOS iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uninstallation

My app was auto Uninstall last night and I spend all day to found how it happened, but found nothing.

Here is the Console log:

```
Nov 5 20:54:48  CommCenter[62] <Notice>: MessageCenterModel is telling PDP context -1 to go active.
Nov 5 20:54:48  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/DSPersonID -> 1110853068
Nov 5 20:54:48  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/DSPersonID -> 1110853068
Nov  5 20:54:48  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/DSPersonID -> 1110853068
Nov  5 20:54:48  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/DSPersonID -> 1110853068
Nov  5 20:54:48  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/DSPersonID -> 1110853068
Nov  5 20:54:49  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/downloaded-apps -> <CFArray 0x1f533830 [0x3d1f9100]>{type = immutable, count = 9, values = (
        0 : <CFString 0x1f54d7e0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.magikid.numbersflipbook"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1f54d700 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.angellecho.magikidstage"}
        2 : <CFString 0x1f54c1c0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "net.delusionstudio.cocomongslabfree"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1f54cdf0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.magikid.MagKidTail"}
        4 : <CFString 0x1f54b5d0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.angellecho.magikid.train"}
        5 : <CFString 0x1f5335b0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.subsplashstudio34.Church-of-the-Foothills"}
        6 : <CFString 0x1f54d910 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.bingoapp.yzjj.MagicSong"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1f54d0c0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.trisw.Pinocchio"}
        8 : <CFString 0x1f54c3b0 [0x3d1f9100]>{contents = "com.scholarandsaint.paddywhacks"}
    )}
Nov  5 20:54:52  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2ff83000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/PurchaseTypes -> (null)
Nov  5 20:54:52  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2fe93000 set_itunes_value: set com.apple.mobiffle.iTunes.store/LibraryCUID to b4e09adbe3c01c22e1e68d4b6bb09ae5 succeeded
Nov  5 20:55:01  installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ff98000 handle_uninstall: Uninstall requested by atc
Nov  5 20:55:02  installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ff98000 MobileInstallationUninstall_Server: Uninstalling com.**.**
Nov  5 20:55:02  SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: Killing com.**.** for termination assertion
Nov  5 20:55:02  lsd[698] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file
Nov  5 20:55:02  lsd[698] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file
Nov  5 20:55:02  installd[31] <Error>: 0x20e000 __block_global_6: LS failed to unregister application file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/8D93D99D-7D7F-41CE-9093-3C24E1EA3F1C/**.app/ (com.**.**)
Nov  5 20:55:02  SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Nov  5 20:55:02  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.**.**[0xf31a]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov  5 20:55:02  backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.**.**[0xf31a]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov  5 20:55:03  SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: An application that SpringBoard is not tracking with bundle identifier com.**.** just exited.
Nov  5 20:55:03  SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: No transaction in -[SBWorkspace workspace:applicationWillBecomeReceiver:fromApplication:]
Nov  5 20:55:03  SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: No transaction in -[SBWorkspace workspace:applicationDidBecomeReceiver:fromApplication:]
Nov  5 20:55:03  installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ff98000 __MobileInstallationClearUninstalled_Server_block_invoke_0: Removing id com.angellecho.iphone.drluke from uninstalled list
```

You can see `Uninstall requested by atc`. I wonder what `atc` is.

As console log, you can see the system kill my app when it running. When I am back to the desktop, the icon disappeared!

My iPhone is not jailBreak. My app is in compiled in Debugger configuration (according to XCode).

Comment: Uninstall? From where? iPhone?..Please clarify

Comment: may be it will be shifted into some folder.check it again by writing its name in search screen

Comment: Sorry,yes.It's uninstall from iphone

Comment: Is your iPhone managed via any MDM i.e Mobile Device Management?

Comment: Thanks, I just manager app by iTunes